# How to minimise two or more equations in R

Tags: r, estimation

I am trying to find an iterative way to solve these two M-estimater equations with two unknown parameters.

For each patient, we measure his blood pressure twice $Y_{i1}$ and $Y_{i2}$ and note his alcohol consumption $X_i$. We have given the following M-estimators and have proven these give unbiased results:

$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^2\big(Y_{ij}-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i\big)=0\quad\mbox{and }
\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^2\big(Y_{i}-\beta_0-\beta_1X_i\big)X_i=0$$

(Where using OLS or maximum likelihood we assume all the measurements are independent).

I know it is possible to solve these analytically, but in case these two equations would be very complex, how do I solve these numerically in R?

Is there something like `nlm` for multiple equations?

Comment: I'm confused - if you rewrite each equation in terms of $Y_i = \cdots$ you will see that the two equations are the same. A more general way to approach this though is to stack the equations and then form the design matrix to estimate the parameters of interest.

Comment: I am confused as well and tried to clarify the question better

Comment: @AndyW can it be that I have to minimise the norm of the two outcomes?

Comment: @user603 I don't get what you mean, shouldn't I take the norm of the values of the sums and minimise this norm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I should have done is minimise the norm of the two equations, and `nlm` is able to minimise a function with two unknown variables. This R script works fine:

```
y <- data_long$y
x <- data_long$x

f <- function(beta){
  temp_1 <- sum(y - beta[1] - beta[2] * x) 
  temp_2 <- sum(x*(y - beta[1] - beta[2] * x))
  sqrt(temp_1^2 + temp_2^2)
}
m_estimator <- nlm(f, c(0,0))
```

With data_long my simulated data, and beta my two estimates.